# trumbowyg custom button btnsDef is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, editor, trumbowyg

```
$('.trumbowyg').trumbowyg({
btnsDef: {
    dropdownButtonName: {
        dropdown: ['btnA', 'btnB'],
        title: 'Displayed dropdown button name',
        ico: 'iconName',
        hasIcon: true
    }
}
```

});
When trying to add Custom drop down to the trumbowyg is not working

Answer (score 2):

You must also add new button to btns in trumbowyg button pane.

```
$('.trumbowyg').trumbowyg(
  {
  btnsDef:
    {
    dropdownButtonName: 
      {
      dropdown: ['btnA', 'btnB'],
      title: 'Displayed dropdown button name',
      ico: 'iconName',
      hasIcon: true
      }
    }
 btns:
   [
     ['dropdownButtonName']
   ]
 });
```